# vim - remapping leader has no effect?

Tags: vim, macvim

On MacVim, I'm trying to remap leader to ' (single quote), and change `'` to `\`. However

```
let mapleader="'"
nnoremap \ '
```

is having no effect after `:w` and `:so %`. Nor does `let mapleader=","` seem to remap it to `,`.

Am I doing it correctly? Any help? Thanks!

Comment: do you put the `let mapleader="'"` at the beginning of .vimrc? leader is only effect when setting map after setting leader. and won't effect the previous bindings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing `mapleader` only affects *new* mappings that use the `<Leader>` special key. So, you need to set this in your `~/.vimrc` and restart Vim so that all plugins correctly pick this up.

If I understand you right, you then want to map <kbd>\</kbd> to `'`, in order to use the jump mark command without the delay introduced by using that key for the Leader now, right? That should be fine.

Comment: Yeah, just basically swap these two keys.

Comment: You're right. I had to restart Vim. Only using `:so ~/.vimrc` doesn't work. So for some of the changes one has to restart, not only reload the `.vimrc` file? Why's that though.

Comment: `<leader>` isn't a special key at all. It is a constant of sort, used by Vim when sourcing your `vimrc` and registering your custom mappings. If your `<leader>` is set to `,` your mapping is registered as `,<key>` and changing `<leader>` ro anything else has no effect on existing mappings. If you want to override your existing mappings after you have changed your `<leader>` your only solution is to restart Vim.